# Define dependencies in packages configuration in Dojo Toolkit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dojo

can i define jQuery as a dependency for Bootstrap js so that is loads before Bootstrap? For example:

```
 var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    baseUrl:'/',
    packages: [
      {name: "dojo", location: "lib/dojo"},
      {name: "dijit", location: "lib/dijit"},
      {name: "dojox", location: "lib/dojox"},
      {name: "jquery", location: "lib/jquery", main: "jquery-3.1.1.min"},
      {name: "bootstrap", location: "lib/bootstrap", main: "bootstrap.min"}
    ]

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Modules will be added as scripts in your document in same order as you use them in require function. For example:

```
require(["jquery","bootstrap"], function (jquery, bootstrap) {
            //some code here
        });
```

Will generate following:

```
...
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="path_to_jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="path_to_bootstrap"></script>
...
</body>
```

Hope it's what you were asking about.

Comment: I have tried this but still getting `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: Oh, curiuos. But why don't you add links to jqery and bootstrap libs in page body? Why it's needed to use them as AMD modules?